# Insert node to ElementTree tree at specific level by name

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

If I have an XML ElementTree with unknown depth, I want to insert a node as a child node to a specific parent (known). The code I have so far (from some other threads) is as following:

`my_tree.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <country name="Singapore">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>      
    </holidays>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
</data>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = "my_tree.xml"

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()


newNode = ET.Element('christmas')
newNode.text = 'Yes'


root.insert(0, newNode)
```

Above, it inserts directly under `root`. If I want to insert it below a node named `<holidays>` (not knowing its depth level in the real data), how do I point `root` to this level? Thanks.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks. I have updated with the XML tree and the code. Hope someone could help. Also, I try to avoid ```append``` because for some reason, ```append``` messes up the indentation of the whole file, while ```insert``` at the beginning (location ```0```) does not. I try to avoid extra work with pretty-printing for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there; just replace your last line with

```
target = root.find('.//holidays')    
target.insert(0, newNode)
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <country name="Singapore">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>      
    </holidays>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
</data>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
holidays = root.find('.//holidays')
newNode = ET.Element('christmas')
newNode.text = 'Yes'
holidays.append(newNode)
ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This is similar to @Jack Fleeting's solution. Since I saw his response before this, I have accepted his.

Comment: sure. no problem :-)